# My application cannot access g suite users Google calendar

Tags: google-calendar-api

I have a web app that manages users' Google Calendar. Recently, I got an "invalid credential" error when retriving calendar list and figured out the user account is a g suite account (because of different domain). However, I still can get the access token as well as refresh token. I also can get open ID information from the account. But just cannot access the calendar. Other accounts ends with gmail.com worked fine.

Did I miss anything in authentication for these g suite users?

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/errors#401_invalid_credentials), this error usually occurs if the access token you're using is either expired or invalid.

Here are additional links which might also help:

- [Error accessing Google Calendar using OAuth2.0. and service account: "Invalid impersonation prn email address."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51241711/error-accessing-google-calendar-using-oauth2-0-and-service-account-invalid-im)
- [Invalid credentials: Google API calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25389960/invalid-credentials-google-api-calendar)
- [Google Calendar API 401 "Invalid Credentials"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41759001/google-calendar-api-401-invalid-credentials)